# How to sum fields after group_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, group-by

I need to group some records by date, then sum one field for each of those days.

This is the code I'm trying to refactor:

```
<% @startdate.upto(@enddate) do |date| %>
  <% visitors = @links.where("created_at >= ? AND created_at < ?", date, date+1).order("created_at ASC").select("id, visit_count") %>
  <%= datevisitors.sum("visit_count") || 0 %>
<% end %>
```

I've started with:

```
<% visitors = @links.select("visit_count, created_at").group_by{|l| l.created_at.day} %>
<% @startdate.upto(@enddate) do |date| %>
  <%= visitors[date] ...?
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you group_by something, you receive an array of the day and the element. So if you group by day, you'll have the Day and the elements that are part of the array:

```
<% @links.group_by{|l| l.created_at.day}.each do |day, links| %>
  <p><%= day %>: <%= links.sum(&:visit_count) %></p>
<% end %>
```

EDIT --

OK, in that case your code looks like it was very close:

```
<% visitors = @links.select("visit_count, created_at").group_by{|l| l.created_at.day} %>
<% @startdate.upto(@enddate) do |date| %>
  <% if visitors[date] %>
    <%= visitors[date].sum(&:visit_count) %>
  <% else %>
    0
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It's probably better to move this to a helper (or presenter)

```
def daily_visits(links, from, to)
  links_by_day = links.select("visit_count, created_at").group_by{|l| l.created_at.day}
  range = from.upto(to).to_a
  range.inject({}) do |date, hash|
    hash[date] = links_by_day.fetch(date, 0)
  end
end
```

Then, in the view:

```
<% daily_visits(@links, @startdate, @enddate).each do |day, count| %>
  <%= day %>: <%= count %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jesse. In my situation the @links don't necessarily have a positive value for each and every day, so this solution can gloss over 0-value days.

Comment: @sscirrus I updated my answer to show the 0 days from your solution

Answer (score 0):

This should be on controller

```
@dates_with_visitors = @links.select("visit_count, created_at").group_by(&:created_at)
```

This should be on the view

```
<% @dates_with_visitors.each do |date_with_visitors| %>
  <%= "#{date_with_visitor[0]} - Visits: #{date_with_visitors[1].sum(&:visit_count)}" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you give me the Model that will be used?

Here's my example on a Activerecord with a aggregate sum function:

```
<% @sum_visit_count = Visitor.find(:all, :select => "SUM(visit_count)", :group => "id, date_visit") %>

and 

<%= @sum_visit_count.sum %>
```